# Problem with my odoo installation on ubuntu server

Tags: python, ubuntu, odoo

After installing odoo 12 on ubuntu server I tried to check odoo status with systemctl status odoo. Here's what I got in the output:

```
odoo.service - Odoo Open Source ERP and CRM 
Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/odoo.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled) 
Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2019-07-05 21:04:51 CEST; 10s ago 
Process: 10541 ExecStart=/usr/bin/odoo --config /etc/odoo/odoo.conf --logfile /var/log/odoo/odoo-server.log (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE 
Main PID: 10541 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE) 

Jul 05 21:04:51 vps706653 odoo[10541]: from . import db, graph, loading, migration, module, registry 
Jul 05 21:04:51 vps706653 odoo[10541]: File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/modules/loading.py", line 17, in 
Jul 05 21:04:51 vps706653 odoo[10541]: import odoo.modules.migration 
Jul 05 21:04:51 vps706653 odoo[10541]: File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/modules/migration.py", line 12, in 
Jul 05 21:04:51 vps706653 odoo[10541]: from odoo.modules.module import get_resource_path 
Jul 05 21:04:51 vps706653 odoo[10541]: File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/modules/module.py", line 12, in 
Jul 05 21:04:51 vps706653 odoo[10541]: import pkg_resources 
Jul 05 21:04:51 vps706653 odoo[10541]: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pkg_resources' 
Jul 05 21:04:51 vps706653 systemd[1]: odoo.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE 
Jul 05 21:04:51 vps706653 systemd[1]: odoo.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

Please help
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are missing `pkg_resources`. So to install the module `pkg_resources`(which is part of `setuptools`) on your server, you can do this with `pip install setuptools`.